# pandas: how to save to hdf dataframe with string columns containing np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, hdf5

I am wondering if there is a good way to save a pandas dataframe to hdf when it contains string columns.

Given the dataframe :

```
In [6]: df.head()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[6]:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
   Protocol           Src   Bytes                                                                                                                                                                                  
10     ICMP           NaN    1062                                                                                                                                                                                  
11     ICMP     10.2.0.74    2146                                                                                                                                                                                  
12     ICMP  10.100.100.1  857520                                                                                                                                                                                  
13     ICMP  10.100.100.2  857520                                                                                                                                                                                  
14     ICMP  10.100.100.2    7000
```

`df.to_hdf('save.h5' ,'table')` results in:

```
/home/lpuggini/MyApps/python_2_7_numerical/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:1138: PerformanceWarning:                                                                                            
your performance may suffer as PyTables will pickle object types that it cannot                                                                                                                                    
map directly to c-types [inferred_type->mixed,key->block0_values] [items->['Protocol', 'Src']]                                                                                                                     

  return pytables.to_hdf(path_or_buf, key, self, **kwargs)
```

This message can be avoided casting the columns to `str` as:

`df['Src'] = df['Src'].apply(str)`

but then also the `np.nan` will be saved as `'nan'`

Is there a better way to save dataframe containing columns with `string` and `np.nan`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Columns in an HDF file must be of a single dtype. `nan` is represented by a `float` internally to numpy. You could replace the `nan` values with empty strings via:

```
df['src'].fillna('')
```

HDF performs much better on numeric types than strings, so it may make more sense to convert your IP address to an integer type.

Edit: see @Jeff's note below. The above is true for format='fixed'.

Edit2: According to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#storing-mixed-types-in-a-table), you can specify the on-disk representation for nan for string dtype cols:

```
df.to_hdf((...), nan_rep='whatever you want')
```

Comment: In addition to this, you could save another column or table of boolean values that you can use as a mask for nulling string values when you retrieve them.

Comment: this is only correct for fixed format; table format DOES support mill values in object dtypes (strings); these are converted to/from